# Spring Boot Rest Controller Stale Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cxf

I have implemented a rest controller using Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE

At the start of day, many applications on the network make requests to a single running instance of my controller.

I believe I am seeing parameters from multiple applications being combined in a single call to the controller

For example, the business logic in my controller throws an exception when it receives the following URL which I log as soon as the controller is called:

```
2021-02-19 06:31:05.551 [http-nio-9000-exec-6] [ERROR] [RefDataServerController]: http://tbaquaappc-u2:9000/refdata/exec/text/getParticipantBitCross?instance=LINEDATA&cert=0dk7lc0vyeVEPptGwVyUXc%3DNbc0FW3IujbPTF7e&cert=Hzj%2Fqu9tIw865CMmsEP076N9mgLI3J6oFwovyt1
```

In this URL there are 2 '&cert' parameters which no application sends.

Two distinct applications send the following independent requests (at about the same time)

```
http://tbaquaappc-u2:9000/refdata/exec/text/getParticipantBitCross?instance=LINEDATA&cert=Hzj%2Fqu9tIw865CMmsEP076N9mgLI3J6oFwovyt1

http://tbaquaappc-u2:9000/refdata/exec/text/getParticipantBitCross?instance=JOHN2&cert=0dk7lc0vyeVEPptGwVyUXc%3DNbc0FW3IujbPTF7e
```

It looks like the &cert from the second call is getting mingled with the first call.

Comment: If you turn on debug logging in your boot app, do you see two distinct requests received? Do you have any load balancers or gateways or routers or similar which are running between your app and the caller which may be intercepting and changing the requests?

Comment: I do have a gateway in between which forwards the requests from the apps to the controller but I don't see the combined params being from the gateway which also logs what it sends.  I will check it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "Roddy of the Frozen Peas", the problem seems to have indeed been a web proxy which sits in between the Spring Boot app and caller.  The proxy listens for custom protocol requests from a caller on a raw server socket (an unfortunate legacy) and channels them into `JAX-RS` requests to the app.  The proxy listener is standard Java ServerSocket code which block/waits for a request and then calls an input processor on a new thread which forwards the request to the app.  Inside the input processor, I had a class member instance of `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` which simply did a `reset()` before each call inside the `run()` method.  I removed the shared instance and replaced it by having each thread create a new instance of `WebClient` inside the `run()` method before using it to forward http requests to the app.  That seems to have fixed the issue.  Probably `WebClient` is not thread safe.